# JavaScript multidimensional get value without looping

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a question,

I've got an array in Javascript that looks like this:

```
var plans = [{
'advanced':[{
    'price':'10',
    'name':'Advanced'
    }],
'basic':[{
    'price':'20',
    'name':'Basic'
    }]
}];
```

And there's a variable called **plan**, this could be advanced or basic etc. Now I want to display the price from the array that corresponds with the variable **plan**. How do I get the price?

I've tried things like:

- plans.advanced.price
- plans['advanced']['price']
- plans[0].advanced['0'].price
- plans[0]['advanced']['0']['price']

PS: I am originally A PHP developer, maybe my PHP influence is blocking the correct thoughts, i dont know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access it like this: `plans[0].advanced[0].price`

That's the wrong way to be going about it though; just use JavaScript objects:

```
var plans = {
    advanced: {
        price: '10',
        name: 'Advanced'
    },
    basic: {
        price: '20',
        name:' Basic'
    }
};
```

Then you can access it using `plans.advanced.price`, which is much more clear.

Note that `plans.advanced.price` is the same as `plans['advanced']['price']` in JavaScript, there is no difference.

Arrays in JavaScript are just glorified objects - as such there is no such thing as "associative arrays" in JavaScript, objects perform the same thing as associative arrays in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

you have some extra array cruft, where you have arrays with one item in them instead of just having the object.

```
var plans = {
   advanced: {
     price: '10',
     name: 'Advanced'
   },
   basic: {
     price: '20',
     name:' Basic'
   }
};
```

if you have `var plan ="advanced"` you can just do `plans[plan].price`

if you NEED the current structure with the arrays then it is essentially the same thing but

```
var plan ="advanced"

plans[0][plan][0].price
```

hope that helps